# Why does CheckStyle suggest that I use a final method?

Tags: java, final, checkstyle

I am using eclipse checkstyle plugin. I have few methods in a class A which are overriden in class B. I have the following warning for most of the methods

> The function `SearchAndReplace` is not conceived to be inherited 
>   - it must be declared abstract or final or leave it empty.

Is there a any advantages to declaring a method as final?

**EDIT**

I know what the keyword final is for. I know it prevents overriding of methods, is there other advantages, like performance or anything like that?

Comment: a final method cannot be overriden !

Comment: I'm curious to know how the plugin can know what the method was conceived as.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you declare a method to be final, you're saying that the method may not be overridden.

Quote from the Java Language Specification:

> A method can be declared final to prevent subclasses from overriding or hiding it.
>
> It is a compile-time error to attempt to override or hide a final method.

The common slogan (due to Joshua Bloch I believe) is

"*Design and Document for Inheritance or Else Prohibit it*"

So, unless your intention is to let subclasses override the method (and potentially change the behavior of the super-class (all methods are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) in Java)) then make the method final.

Answer (score 4):

A `final` method guarantees that no subclasses will override the method.  Chances are that the runtime can take advantage of this for a performance gain (which may be slight).

The main reason for making a method `final` is to stop inheritors overriding the method.  This might be an important consideration (for example, imagine a method called `bool checkSecurity()` - letting others override this would be bad!)

Answer (score 0):

> In Java, final keyword is applied in various context:
>
> The final keyword is a modifier means the final class can't be extended, a variable can't be modified, and also a method can't be override.

Answer (score 0):

When a method is declared as final it safe to be invoked in constructor(unless other non final methods are invoked in it). If it is not final subclases can override it in a way which tries to access fields introduced in the subclass. And this will often be not what you expect.
i think there is some performence benefit when you write for mobile devices but i am not expert there.